# How do I prove this is correct when taken to infinity?

Tags: proof-verification

$\frac{35*87}{67*59}$ = $\frac{30*18.\overline{45}}{(39*18.\overline{45}) - 1}$

edited version:

Step by step, how would I prove that the left and right sides are exactly equal using fractional math only (no decimal math)?

$\frac{35*87}{67*59}$ = $\frac{30*18\frac{45}{99}}{(39*18\frac{45}{99}) - 1}$

Comment: i don't what you want to ask, please specify your problem

Comment: Rewrite $18.\overline{45}$ as $18+\frac5{11}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the usual technique for converting repeating decimals to fractions, prove that $$0.\overline {45}=\frac {45}{99}$$  Now plug that into your equation.

Added:  now use $18\frac {45}{99}=\frac {1827}{99}$ because mixed fractions are a pain.  So
$$\frac{30*18\frac{45}{99}}{(39*18\frac{45}{99}) - 1}=\frac {30 \cdot\frac {1827}{99}}{39\cdot \frac{1827}{99}-1}\\
=\frac{30\cdot 1827}{39\cdot 1827-99}\\
=\frac{35\cdot 87 \cdot 18}{71154}\\=
\frac{35\cdot 87 \cdot 18}{67\cdot59\cdot18}\\
=\frac{35\cdot 87}{67\cdot 59}$$

Comment: I have reformatted my question using your answer as help.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you, sir!